# Facebook Like ( in Modal Window ) change location_href

Tags: html, location-href

We use PrettyPhoto and newest incarnation 3.1.3 allows users to Like and Tweet within the Modal Window..

This is great, but it doent work (fb that is ). I am yet to find anyone who has got this working, even PrettyPhoto site itself.

Anyway, I really would like to use this. The issue i think is how the url is parsed.

Prettyphoto js code for the iframe like button is..

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=en_US&href={location_href}&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The key seems to be {location_href}

IS this correct formatting ? Before you ask, yep asked on PrettyPhoto support, but alas theres a whole heap of people asking exactly the same questions with no answer.

I think the js they are using is wrong.

To add: tried parent_location_href but doesnt parse correctly, also parent.location_href and all different connotations..

Looks like I may have to put absolute link is... or should i put site url followed by location_href

Like http://mydomain.com/{location_href}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no iframe version of the like button supported by Facebook. Please see here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

I would use the xfbml version and follow Tue documentation to do this by adding the namespace and asynchronously load the fb js SDK.

Edit: here is a quick guide

Put this code straight after the opening body tag

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=265199713527696";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Alter your HTML tag to have this namespace

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Then put your xfbml like button in modal replacing values as needed

```
<fb:like href="http://yoururl.com" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

You might want to use the fb lint to help check what details are picked up by facebook and refresh any data for a url. This can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I have edited my answer to include more detail to help you along. Also at some point you may want to mark the answer if the info provided is useful or this will become yet another open ended question.

Comment: Weird, cos on facebook they offer three versions, html5 , xfmbl and iframe. Thanks, already tried above and using the js sdk. I have it working, but iframe mode seems to render href issues. Hence my question, in fact I have it working perfectly with html5. The issue now is on clicking like the status window opens, but because its in a modal window it is hdden from view, is there a way of hiding the add status comments after hitting like ?